# How to create a Loop in python web scraping for listing

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, pagination

I'm scraping a dynamic website and trying to find a way to change the value of     **start** for every time and then perform the whole task and collect the data and want to append in **data_list**.

```
start = 0
start = 500
start = 1000
start = 1500
```

How can I change the value of **strat** in **api_request_url** for every time?

```
api_request_url = f"https://www.ellsworth.com/api/catalogSearch/search?sEcho=1&iDisplayStart={start}&iDisplayLength={n_items}&DefaultCatalogNode=Adhesives&_=1497895052601"
```

Here is the Code

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
data_list = []

start = 0
n_items = 500
api_request_url = f"https://www.ellsworth.com/api/catalogSearch/search?sEcho=1&iDisplayStart={start}&iDisplayLength={n_items}&DefaultCatalogNode=Adhesives&_=1497895052601"
data = requests.get(api_request_url).json()
bas_url    = 'https://www.ellsworth.com'
print(f"Found: {data['iTotalRecords']} items.")
for item in data["aaData"]:
    data_list.append(base_url+item[4])
```

Comment: I see that you are new to Stack Overflow.  I would recommend that you read this: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

The API returns something which is called a batch - 10 pieces of data, starting from `start`.

You can just create a `for` loop and change the value of `api_request_url` every time:

```py
n_items = 500

for start in range(0, n_items, 10):
    api_request_url = f"https://www.ellsworth.com/api/catalogSearch/search?sEcho=1&iDisplayStart={start}&iDisplayLength={n_items}&DefaultCatalogNode=Adhesives&_=1497895052601"
    # Do your stuff
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the start choices to a list and iterate the list:

```
lststart = [0,500,1000,1500]

for start in lststart:
    n_items = 500
    api_request_url = f"https://www.ellsworth.com/api/catalogSearch/search?sEcho=1&iDisplayStart={start}&iDisplayLength={n_items}&DefaultCatalogNode=Adhesives&_=1497895052601"
    .................
```